# How to display specific navbar when logged in?

Tags: html, django, authentication

I have created 2 navbars, one for when user is logged in and one for when they are not. I need to display the correct navbar dependending upon if the user is logged in or not. I know i need to check in Django with something like this,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% return navbarLogged %}
{% else %}
{% return navbarsignup %}
```

But I'm confused on what I should include in my return and where exactly to put this in my code.

Should I add this to my base.html? Or, can i just create a function in my models and then call the function at the beginning of base.html?

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <nav> navbar to show when authenticated </nav>

{% else %}

    <nav> navbar to show when user is not authenticated </nav>

{% endif %}
```

and you can use it on your base html if the navbar is used in all pages